# Unable to push object into array in Mongodb collection but Id is inserted

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am using comment array in my schema as fallows. I want to push comments data into that comment array using nodejs api

```
    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;


 var myfeeds = new Schema({
title: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
feed: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
createdBy: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
},
createdDate: {
    type: Date,
    required: true,
    default: Date.now()
},

comment: [
    {
        commentBy: {
            type: String
        },
        commentText: {
            type: String
        },
        createdDate: {
            type: Date
        }
    }
],
likes: [
    {
        likesCount: {
            type: Number,
            required: false
        },
        likeBy: {
            type: String,
            required: false
        }
    }
]
  });
```

I want to push object to this comment array. so, for that I did in this way please tell me if anything wrong in this

```
let _id = req.body.id;
let commentBy = req.body.commentedBy;
let commentedText = req.body.commentedText;
let commentedDate = req.body.commentedDate;
let data = {
    commentBy: commentBy,
    commentText: commentedText,
    createdDate: commentedDate
};

MyFeeds.findByIdAndUpdate(
    { _id: _id },
    {
        $push: {
            comment: data
        }
    }
)
    .then((result) => {
        res.status(200).json({
            status: result
        });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        res.status(500).json({
            status: 'invalid',
            err: err
        });
    });
```

but only id are inserted into that comment array but not the required content

```
    "comment": [
                   {
            "_id": "5badfd092b73fa14f4f0aa7c"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5badfd102b73fa14f4f0aa7d"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5badfd142b73fa14f4f0aa7e"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5badfd31500fb11bb06b4c8a"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5badfd35500fb11bb06b4c8b"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5badff3d439a151190d62961"
        }
    ],
```

Comment: show the mongoose schema of MyFeeds. It could be a problem there. Also in findByIdAndUpdate -> You can put id directly as first parameter instead of {_id : _id}. 
You can do MyFeeds.findByIdAndUpdate( _id , {$push: {comment: data}}).then()

Comment: same problem no change

Comment: Can you show the schema of MyFeeds?

Comment: see top of the post that is the schema

Comment: thanks, the problem is with form parameters